# This question is NOT a duplicate!

Tags: support

[How can I transfer system data to a new 3DS without using System Transfer?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/110177/53648)

This has been marked as a duplicate, but the linked question is a totally different one. This question is asking if you can transfer data from an old 3DS to a new one without using System Transfer. The linked question is about if you can change SD cards while retaining data.

It should be unmarked.

Comment: You're a little late to the party for this request.  That was closed over 6 months ago.  You're going to have to convince us with more evidence that these questions aren't dupes _according to our standards for closing_.  Right now, I agree with the closers that the linked question is in fact a dupe.

Comment: Wait, so the answer in the master question do not work?

Comment: @MBraedley - whilst I agree the question is a dupe, the lateness of a request such as this should not be taken into account when determining whether to reopen </nitpick>

Answer (score 6):

It seems that the closers of the question agree that although the question may be worded differently, the answers are the same.

Duplicates don't always have to be the result of poor searching beforehand and not finding an already posted question, often they are signposts showing that one question is just another way of asking the same thing; such that future visitors can find their answer in two different ways of asking.